# Reading from socketCAN inside a driver

Tags: drivers, ipc, canbus

I am attempting to read a socketCAN device inside a driver.

I am setting up an skb and passing that along with pertinent information to the `can_rx_register` call to register a callback named `sc_rcv`.

```C
// callback
static void sc_rcv(struct sk_buff *skbr, void *data)

// initialization
result = can_rx_register(&init_net, dev, 10 | CAN_INV_FILTER, CAN_SFF_MASK, &sc_rcv, skb, "mycan", 0);
```

I am able to receive packets but I get repeated packets and I'm not sure why.

I am looking for an example of how this is implemented.